# How can I access files in the /sys folder of milestone/droid from java?

Tags: android

I want to access files in the /sys, to be exact in the /sys/class folder. I just need to read some values there.
I tried the Context.openFileInput method, but got only exceptions and I understand this is not the right way.

thanks for replying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for you to read the contents of anything in `/sys` on a production Android device, except those that have been rooted by their users. Sorry
!